# How to check if Japanese version of Wikidata item exists

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to build a list of names and match them to their Japanese equivalents.

I first thought about trying to crawl Wikipedia and following a link to the Japanese version of the page but I didn't know how to check whether the page was about a person or anything else.

Thankfully there's the wikidata and dbpedia projects.

I started tinkering with wikidata and found this example 
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples#People_born_before_year_1880_with_no_death_date

which can be shrunk to a query for 'people'

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
   ?h wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .

 } LIMIT 1
```

That results in a link for George Washington
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q23

At the bottom of that page is a list of links to wikipedia pages for this person 
in other languages including Japanese.

Is there a way of returning the name and Japanese version in the same query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are querying wikidata, you may use label service:

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q30 p:P6/v:P6 ?p .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    ?p rdfs:label ?enName .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ja" .
    ?p rdfs:label ?jaName .
  }
}
```

[Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20v%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20wd%3AQ30%20p%3AP6%2Fv%3AP6%20%3Fp%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%09%3Fp%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FenName%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22ja%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%09%3Fp%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FjaName%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D)

I've found answer [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual)

Comment: Huge thanks, that works perfectly. I'll try and understand more from the links you mentioned also.

Comment: @TmdStrangecharacters mind marking my answer as answer? :)

Comment: If you change the `wd:Q30 p:P6/v:P6 ?p .` into `?p wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q6256 .  ` (list country names in English and Japanese) it times out though – I tried adding `LIMIT 10`, but still timeout :-/

Comment: @unhammer why have you placed `*` mark after wdt:P279 ?

Comment: Aha, removing * solved it, thanks! That was copy-pasta from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples#List_of_countries_ordered_by_the_number_of_their_cities_with_female_mayor – I'm a complete newbie to this sparql stuff